# Will an index be used in a query that includes two column in the where clause with only the first column indexed

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I read that

> if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3)

I'm currently indexing my database tables but I want to know if my query for example contains col1, col2 and col5 in the where clause, will the database still use the index created (col1, col2, col3) even though col5 is not part of the index created?

E.g

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1='male' AND col2='24' AND col5='teacher'
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see the execution plan that will answer your question

Comment: you have 3 column and mysql will find the index if all 3 columns are in it, else it will take the best it can find

Comment: *will the database still use the index* DBMS may use this index. Does it will use the index or not - this depends on table and index statistic. PS. "Use index, use where" in the execution plan means that the index is used, "Use where" means that it is not used.

Comment: @Akina That is not what "Using index" or "Using where" mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySQL can use a subset of an index, as long as the columns are the left-most subset.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table my_table (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(10), col4 varchar(10), col5 varchar(10), key(col1, col2, col3));

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1='male' AND col2='24' AND col5='teacher'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: my_table
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: col1
          key: col1
      key_len: 66
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

EXPLAIN shows you a report of how the optimizer plans to use indexes. In this case, notice `key: col1` which shows which index is chosen, and `ref: const,const` which indicates it will compare two constant values in the query to columns in the index.

If I search on a subset of columns that are not a contiguous left-most columns of the index, it cannot use more than one column of the index. See `ref: const` below, indicating only one value is used to do the lookup.

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1='male' AND col3='24' AND col5='teacher'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: my_table
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: col1
          key: col1
      key_len: 33
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

If I search for a contiguous subset of columns, but they are not the left-most columns of the index, it can't use the index at all. The example below shows that it must resort to a table-scan, indicated by `type: ALL`.

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col2='male' AND col3='24' AND col5='teacher'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: my_table
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Any index *starting* with `(col1, col2)` will be fully used for *that* query.  But, if you change it to, say `WHERE col1 > 5`, it will use only `col1` of the index.  And there are many other exceptions.  So, please provide "real" queries for analysis.

"Using index" means that *all* the columns needed *anywhere* in the `SELECT` were found (not necessarily in the optimal order) in the chosen `INDEX`.  It is called a "covering" index.  "Using where" does not provide much info.

The order of AND'd items in `WHERE` does not matter.  The order in the `INDEX` does matter.

More discussion: [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)